# Angular 8 testing Routing on a Service

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, angular2-routing, angular2-services

I am testing an Http Interception service that uses routing to navigate to another url when it returns an error response, all my tests currently pass as I am not testing the routing itself, however an exception shows up on my console

`Unhandled Promise rejection: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'login' ; Zone: ProxyZone ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'login'`

I have tried putting a spy on my router service on the navigateByUrl function, but it doesn't seem to be being used, as I keep getting the same error, I already tried using RouterTestingModule as well as Router Stubbing, but it looks like my service is simply using another Router Service, not the one provided by my .spec.

Here is my .spec code (I removed my url for work reasons):

```
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { AuthInterceptorService } from './auth-interceptor.service';
import { HttpClientTestingModule, HttpTestingController } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpService } from '../http/http.service';
import { InternalDataService } from '../internal-data/internal-data.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

describe('Service: AuthInterceptor', () => {
  let service: HttpService;
  let httpMock: HttpTestingController;
  let data: InternalDataService;
  let router = {
    navigate: jasmine.createSpy('navigateByUrl')
  };

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        HttpClientTestingModule, 
      ],
      providers: [  
        HttpService, 
        InternalDataService, 
        { 
          provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, 
          useClass: AuthInterceptorService, 
          multi: true 
        }, 
        {
          provide: Router, 
          useValue: router,
        }
      ],
    });

    service = TestBed.get(HttpService);
    httpMock = TestBed.get(HttpTestingController);
    router.navigate.and.callFake(() => {});
  });

  it('deve adicionar o header de autenticação', () => {
    data = TestBed.get(InternalDataService);
    data.setAuthToken('Teste');

    service.getProdutos().subscribe(res => {
      expect(res).toBeTruthy();
    })

    const httpRequest = httpMock.expectOne('<doesnt matter>');
    expect(httpRequest.request.headers.has('Authorization')).toEqual(true);
    expect(httpRequest.request.headers.get('Authorization')).toEqual('Token Teste');
  });
```

and here is my Service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent, HttpResponse, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { InternalDataService } from '../internal-data/internal-data.service';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {
  private token: string;

  constructor(private internal: InternalDataService, private router: Router) {
    this.internal.getAuthToken.subscribe( msg => this.token = msg );
  }

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    if(request.url.match('.*\/auth$') == null) { // ignora se for url de autenticacao
      request = request.clone({
        setHeaders: {
          Authorization: `Token ${this.token}`
        }
      });
    }

    return next.handle(request).pipe(
      catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        if(error.status == 401 || error.status == 403){
          this.internal.setIsAuth(false);
          this.router.navigateByUrl('/login');
        }
        return throwError(error);
      })
    );
  }
}
```

Is anyone able to see what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, apparently we had another test that also did this, and the source of the error was that test, this code works.